# How to populate the $scope on the initial page GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So, my page is dependent upon the fact that the $scope has all the information. I have a lot of `{{ information }}` on the page. On the node backend controller, I get the information from the database and send it to the front end, but the $scope is set in a different file. It's hard to explain what I'm trying to do.

Here is my index.js file:

```
app.get('/page', function (req, res){

   var info = db.getInfo();

   res.render('page', {
      information: info
   });
});
```

The page will then render, but how do I give the information to the $scope.

Comment: how do you make the req-res on the frontend? do you use $http?

Comment: @Shimbr I don't. This GET request is when someone clicks on a link.

Answer (score 0):

The route you've set in your NodeJS needs to be accessed through $http in angular. URL routing should be handled within the front-end application using [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).

If you want to render your page in angular's $scope through the server, you will have to have the server generate the angular code to do so... This is just overcomplicating things however. It's best to let angular handle retrieving that data.

Using an angularjs service:

```
angular.module('yourApp')
  .service('pageLoader', function($http) {
    var baseUrl = ''; // this will be the url for your server. Normally    
                      // 'localhost' or something similar if it is a test 
                      //  environment

    return this.loadPage = function() {
      return $http.get(baseUrl + '/page'); 
    }
  })
  .controller('PageCtrl', function($scope, pageLoader) {
    $scope.page = null;

    $scope.loadPage = function() {
      pageLoader.loadPage().then(function(data) {
        $scope.page = data;
      })
    }
  });
```

This is just to give you an idea of how to do this. There are many different examples of $http services if you do a search.

Also change 'render' to 'send' in your nodejs.

EDIT: Im assuming you are using an angular front-end application and not some sort of other templating system. You should be sending that info and using angular to generate the page with that info.